# Restrict usage of webmethods outside the domain

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a webmethod that will be used on reg form and will check if email address exist in the system.

The method will be called using jquery ajax.

Question is how can I restrict the usage of the webmethod only within my website, so it won't be abused in any other place like local machine running some loop that would load on my server.

I know there is something similar exist for not letting usage of images outside the domain, but have no clue how can it be done for webmethods?

Thanks.

Comment: is this currently a problem? if not the cost of time doesn't outweigh the benefit of such a feature. Plus, are you concerned about the same scenario for an entire page? if not, then why is this a concern at all.

Comment: You can easily prevent your webmethod being run from a malicious javascript code by simply checking request referrer. This will likely cover 90% of what you want. Of course someone could write a couple of line of C# code to construct request manually to try to DoS your site,  but that is more of a sysadmin issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use webmethod from webservice and it appears that it does already restrict the usage of the web method from outer places. But liho1eye comment is pretty right...

So his answer is:

> You can easily prevent your webmethod being run from a malicious
>   javascript code by simply checking request referrer. This will likely
>   cover 90% of what you want. Of course someone could write a couple of
>   line of C# code to construct request manually to try to DoS your site,
>   but that is more of a sysadmin issue.